# Matlab - plotting averages between two structs?

Tags: matlab, plot, average

I am new to Matlab and I think this is a very basic question..

I have two arrays:

```
 tst

  ans =

          0         0    0.2500    0.2500         0         0         0         0

 prp

    ans =

          0         0         0    0.5333    0.0333    0.0333    0.1667    0.0667
```

I want to plot the averages between those two on the same plot (as a line). What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like:

```
# Plot figure
plot(...);

# Calculate the average
avg = mean(tst);

# Add a line to the figure
line(xlim(), [avg avg]);
```

And repeat for `prp`.  You can style the lines however you want according to the [linespec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) documentation.

Note that you should do this at the end of anything that would change the xlimits (`hold`ing and plotting something else, etc.) as it depends on `xlim()`.

**Edit**

I may have misunderstood your question.  The above code will plot a horizontal line at the average of the points in the array `tst`.

If instead you want a line plot whose points are the average of the two arrays, you want something like:

```
# Calculate average between arrays
avg = mean([tst;prp]);

# Plot all 3 lines at once
plot([tst;prp;avg]');
```

Comment: yes thats exactly it. Thanks! I will accept answer as soon as SO lets me )